# Class not found Jaws Wordnet java

Tags: java, wordnet

I am implementing the JAWS API as part of my project. I looked at the example program and have written a similar code.

```
public static String[] generateSynset(String wordForm){
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\ADMINN\\workspace\\NewsExtraction\\WordNet\\2.1\\dict");
    System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", f.toString());

    //setting path for the WordNet Directory
    WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
    Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(wordForm);
```

But even though my code is consistent with their sample program, I keep getting the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/smu/tspell/wordnet/WordNetDatabase
    at Wordnettest.main(Wordnettest.java:11) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.WordNetDatabase
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    ... 1 more
```

I have included the WordNet dictionary database folder correctly.

Can you please help fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add that jar into classPath for the project as well as the server if you are using one.

To do so:

> Right click on project -> Build path -> Configure Build Path -> Add External JARs -> Select JAWS-version.jar
>
> Run -> Run Configurations -> Select your Server -> Class path tab -> Click on User Entries -> Add External JARs -> Select JAWS-version.jar

All the answers I read when I had the issue failed to mention the Run Configuration for the server.

Comment: Thanks man... This solved my issue. You're right no one mentioned about servers!!!